# How to convert a string[] into string?

Tags: java, android, string

I know how to separate the string to string[]. In my project, I use `t = time.split("-")` to split a time into a string array t, and `t[0]=DD, t[1]=MM`. Now I need to convert the string array t into string time with format DD-MM. Did java have functions for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) does:

```
String joined = Joiner.on('-').join(parts);
```

On the other hand, I'd actually suggest *not* splitting and joining your string to start with. Instead, parse it into an appropriate date/time type (ideally [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net)), perform any manipulation you need, and then reformat it using a different format pattern.

This will improve your error detection, and basically make your code really reflect the nature of the data you're working with - instead of just talking about splitting and joining text.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [String Utils from Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) like this:

```
String res = StringUtils.join(myStrings, "-");
```

If you are not looking to use external frameworks, you can roll your own, like this:

```
StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
boolean isFirst = true;
for (String s : myStrings) {
    if (!isFirst) {
        res.append('-');
    } else {
        isFirst = false;
    }
    res.append(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String join(String[] arr, String separator)
{
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(i != 0) b.append(separator);
        b.append(arr[i]);
    }
    return b.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this simple example, what's wrong with this?

```
String time = t[0]+"-"+t[1];
```

Yes, use StringBuilder when performance matters, but this is much more concise.